# How to rotate every line of text by 25 degrees?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, typesetting

Is there a way to rotate each line of text by 25 degrees as seen below? In
Illustrator or Photoshop.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd do this in Illustrator, because it's a lot easier than Photoshop for this particular task, especially if you want to maintain full edibility and easy control over font, leading and be able to paste text in for all labels.

### Step 1 — Draw a text box.

Draw a text box, paste your text in, set a vague font, size and leading, and right align your text.

[image]

### Step 2 — Rotate as needed.

This doesn't need to be perfect, as you can edit later if needed.

[image]

### Step 3 — Edit shape.

Edit the shape so it contains a flat edge at the top, using the Direct Selection Tool (which lets you edit single points, rather than the entire shape).

[image]

The result can be pasted in to Photoshop as a Smart Object, if you'd like.

Comment: Nice solution. Only editing the text is a tiny bit more hard afterwards :)

Comment: Yeah, but you can also edit elsewhere and copy + paste it in. You'll just need the labels to be separated by returns.

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, simply select all the text layers you want to rotate then go to Edit → Transform → Rotate (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then change the angle by 25 degrees.

[image]

Similarly, in Illustrator select your text and go to Object → Transform → Rotate or use the transform panel located in the top bar.

Comment: You might want to add a "align all to top" at the end to achieve the OPs desired look.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator ...

Create two paths at the angle you want, a first path and a last path.

Object > Blend > Make

Object > Blend > Blend Options and set it to Specified Steps and enter the amount of objects you need.

Then choose Object > Expand and tick just the "Object" box and hit OK

Then choose Text > Threaded Text > Create

With the Text Tool, click the first line and start adding your text, hitting return to move to the next line (or paste in the text if you already have it typed).

[image]

You will need to use the Selection Tool (Black Arrow) to move the text I-Beam to the top (Text will be upside down initially until you do this). and you'll want the text right-aligned.

This gives you live text and a line feed (Return) moves to the next line/ You can also move, align, or distribute the paths to adjust the spacing between them.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator: Select all of the text to rotate, Right click → Transform → Transform each → Rotate as desired.

Alternate method: change all text to right justify, select all text and rotate to desired angle, open pathfinder, click align tab, align to top button (assuming you want to align it underneath the graph as pictured above)